# Images in headings should have no bottom margin

Tags: bug, status-completed, formatting, css

See [this answer revision](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/116557/6): the images are floating above the heading's text-bottom line.

[image]

This is caused by images having a `margin-bottom: 0.5em`. This declaration isn't needed inside headings because those headings already have a margin to space them away from surrounding text.

[image]

Instead images inside headings should have `margin-bottom: 0` which will let them sit at text-bottom.

[image]

I suggest adding the following CSS:

```
.post-text h1 img,
.post-text h2 img,
.post-text h3 img {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the years since, styles changed so that the bottom of the image is slightly lower than the descenders, in both regular text and headers:

[image]

It looks good. I'd say [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: That's wonderful news. Looks good to me too.